# Grafana datasources connection using proxy

Tags: grafana

How Grafana can be configured to connect to the data sources (for example Graphite) via proxy?

Grafana -> Proxy -> Graphite

When adding Graphite data source in Grafana there is an option to choose access with proxy (Proxy=Grafana backend will proxy the request) but there is no place in the configureation.ini to specify the IP of the proxy to be used for backend data transfer.

In the ini file there is location to specify "authentication proxy" for accessing the Grafana UI but  can this be used for proxy between Grafana and Graphite?

`[auth.proxy]`

`enabled = true`

`header_name = X-WEBAUTH-USER`

`header_property = username`

`auto_sign_up = true`

Where the proxy details between Grafana and its data sources can be configured?

Thanks for the reply of AussieDan

I have added the environment variables :

```
set HTTP_PROXY="http://proxy_IP:proxy_port"   
set HTTPS_PROXY="https://proxy_IP:proxy_port"
```

And started the Grafana in same command prompt .
When trying to save the Graphite data source in Grafana UI, it says in the log "proxy error: Service Unavailable". Telnet to the proxy on same port works fine so the port is open.

```
`    2016/12/13 15:55:05 http: proxy error: Service Unavailable ←[31mEROR←[0m[12-13|15:55:05] Request Completed                        ←[31mlogger←[0m=context ←[31muserId←[0m=1 ←[31morgId←[0m=1 ←[31muname←[0m=admin ←[31mmethod←[0m=GET ←[31mpath←[0m=/metrics/find ←[31mstatus←[0m=500 ←[31mremote_addr←[0m=IP ←[31mtime_ns←[0m=15ns ←[31msize←[0m=0    `
```

Is there anything additional that needs to be configured for proxy communication?

Answer (score 4):

Grafana defines a new user named `grafana` with its own environment, as stated [here](https://grafana.com/docs/installation/debian/#start-the-server-init-d-service) under **Start the server (init.d service)** and **Environment file** sections.

The environment file on ubuntu is located in `/etc/default/grafana-server`

Paste your proxy environment variable definitions in this file as so:

```
https_proxy=http://<ip>:<port>/
http_proxy=http://<ip>:<port>/
no_proxy=localhost,127.0.0.0/8,::1,<other ip/networks to ignore>
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the grafana backend is written in go, you can use the `HTTP_PROXY="http://proxyIp:proxyPort"` environment variable to specify a proxy for it to use for all outgoing requests.

Comment: What does being written in go have to do with being configurable via environment var?  That's a service-level implementation detail.

Comment: The http library in Go checks for that environment variable and uses it to configure a proxy for all requests using the default Go http client.